# Finding the cycle decomposition of a given permutation.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am given the following permutation and need to find its cycle decomposition: $\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 7 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 9  & 3& 1& \end{array}\right)$.

Following the permutation's instructions, I get the cycles $(179)(2564)(38)$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.